# How to deserialize a nested Buffer using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to serialise and deserialise an object which contains multiple Buffers, however deserialising the resulting string from JSON.stringify() with JSON.parse() fails to correctly re-create the Buffers.

```
var b64 = 'Jw8mm8h+agVwgI/yN1egchSax0WLWXSEVP0umVvv5zM='; 
var buf = new Buffer(b64, 'base64');

var source = {
    a: {
        buffer: buf
    }
};

var stringify = JSON.stringify(source);
var parse = JSON.parse(stringify);

console.log("source: "+source.a.buffer.constructor.name);
console.log("parse: "+parse.a.buffer.constructor.name);
```

Gives the ouput:

```
source: Buffer
parse: Object
```

This makes sense since the output from Buffer.toJSON() creates a simple object like so:

```
{
  type: "Buffer",
  data: [...]
}
```

I guess I could traverse the resulting object looking for sub objects that have the above properties and convert them back to a Buffer, however I feel there should be a more elegant solution using JSON.parse() that I am missing.

Comment: No, there's nothing more elegant. The only structured data types that JSON supports are objects and arrays. `JSON.parse` doesn't know anything about `Buffer`. The `Buffer.toJSON` method is simply translating the buffer into something that `JSON.parse` can understand.

Comment: You can pass a ["reviver" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to `JSON.parse` in order to avoid the manual traversal. When you find the `buffer` property, you'll take the value and manually create and return your `Buffer`.

Comment: @squint we thought the same thing, sorry if I "stole" your answer :-)

Comment: @robertklep: Nope, not at all. I'd have posted it below if I felt like it. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) that checks if an object looks like a stringified `Buffer`, and create a proper instance from it:

```
var parse = JSON.parse(stringify, (k, v) => {
  if (
    v !== null            &&
    typeof v === 'object' && 
    'type' in v           &&
    v.type === 'Buffer'   &&
    'data' in v           &&
    Array.isArray(v.data)) {
    return new Buffer(v.data);
  }
  return v;
});
```

Comment: Just curious, where are `type` and `data` coming from?

Comment: @squint those are the properties of the object that a `Buffer` gets stringified to.

Comment: I don't get those properties when I stringify a Buffer. Are you sure?

Comment: @squint `JSON.stringify(new Buffer('foo'))` -> `{"type":"Buffer","data":[102,111,111]}` (Node v4.2.1)

Comment: @robertklep, Just a note, this fails with `null` values.  Since `typeof null` is `"object"`.  Try this with `{ "foo": null }` and you get errors (because you can't enumerate over a `null`).

Comment: @Jamen good point. It also should check if `v.data` is an array as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I get `[102,111,111]`. What version of NodeJS are you using. Mine is `0.10.25`

Comment: Been a while since I used node. :-) Thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you meant `Array.isArray(v.data)`. I'll be quite now. :D

Comment: @robertklep - thank you!  I had to change the (k, v) => to function (k, v) - (due to node version v0.12.4 perhaps?), but this appears to work exactly as required.

Comment: @robertklep apologies for missing the reviver parameter with JSON.parse() - I am just getting up to speed with node.js and a little swamped at the moment :)

Comment: @GeekyDeaks I don't think it's a very well-known option amongst JS developers :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since JSON serializes `Buffer`s to:

```
{
  type: "Buffer",
  data: [...]
}
```

You can just check the `type` and reinitialize a buffer:

```
if (source.buf.type === 'Buffer') {
  source.buf = new Buffer(source.buf.data);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure he knows how to create a buffer. He's asking how to have it parsed to a Buffer automatically. *"...I could traverse the resulting object looking for sub objects that have the above properties and convert them back to a Buffer, however I feel there should be a more elegant solution..."*

Comment: And he probably doesn't have the `source`. I really doubt he's actually doing a `stringify` immediately followed by a `parse`.

Comment: @squint Whoops, should have read more closely.  Robertklep's answer does the job then.